# A single word for "competences I want to acquire"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word or term that describes *"competences I want to acquire"* or *"skills I want to learn"*.

This stands opposite to "things I already know or can do", as in "my competences" and "my skills"; which are things I already learned. Opposite to that, are the things I still want to learn.

*Objectives*, and *Goals* come to mind, but to me (being a non-native English speaker) those don't entirely fit, I might be wrong. *Goal* seems more of a *target*, a 'place' where I want to end up. And objective is far broader, it can be used for "skills I want to learn" but also for "today's objective is to finish before 5".

Comment: Are they aspirations?

Comment: @YosefBaskin: I am not entirely familiar with that word, but yes! It seems to fit. Unclear to me, if whether it is "positive": as in: is it something I want to learn (and become a better person?) as would be the case with "intentions"?

Comment: If you can truthfully say that you are at least slightly engaged (e.g. looking at course catalogs) toward acquiring each of these skills, I would say *In Progress*.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane, I've fixed the spelling.

Comment: @berkes How could an [*aspiration* (from the verb *aspire*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspire): "to seek to attain or accomplish a particular goal") be negative in any practical way? Why would anybody aspire to have a bad thing happen to them—especially if they didn't *want* it to happen to them?

Comment: @JasonBassford to me, it seems it would indeed not have a negative connotation. But English is not my, nor my countries first or second language. So I often miss small details like a connotation. Thanks for clarifying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had been a comment, but I'm adding it as an answer, since, after clarification, it satisfies the question.

Competencies that you want to acquire, objectives and goals in a subjectively positive sense, are [**aspirations**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aspiration):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : a strong desire to achieve something high or great
>        // an *aspiration* to become famous
> —usually plural
>        // a young man with political/literary *aspirations*
> **2 b** : an object of such desire
>        // An acting career is her *aspiration*.